# DIV scrolling despite overflow being hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV that looks like this:

```
<div style="height:300px;"> Content... </div>
```

I'm using JavaScript to shorten the DIV height. After shortening it, I do not want the cut-off text to be readable. So I use:

```
$("div").css("height", "150px").css("overflow-y","hidden");
```

Using Chrome Inspector, I can tell that overflow-y is being applied, but the DIV is still scrollable after it is shortened, which I don't want. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: can you prepare a jsFiddle?

Comment: It's still vertically scrollable?

Comment: I just tried this (http://jsfiddle.net/MsAr4/) in chrome and it looks fine, but IE seems to react differently. Also the jQuery Version seems to play a role, in 2.* it doesn't work on IE in 1.9 it does. Maybe that helps.

Comment: what about `overflow` instead of `overflow-y`?

Comment: If you are refering to the bug in chrome i think, try that: `$("div").css("height", "150px").css("overflow-y","hidden").off('scroll').on('scroll',function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
}); `  http://jsfiddle.net/5d56b/

Comment: I forgot to mention an important point: this is web app to be used exclusively in iPhone and Android browsers. A. Wolff, I tried your suggestion about .on('scroll', but unfortunately I am still able to scroll through the hidden content of the DIV, despite the fact that its overflow-y is hidden, by tapping on text content and dragging my finger tip down.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$("div").css("height", "150px").css("overflowY","hidden");
```

The dash might be causing the issue

Comment: Thanks for your response, Andy. The CSS directive is being applied to the element, according to Chrome Inspector, so that's not the issue. The problem is that somehow the DIV content continues to scroll despite the overflow-y being set to hidden.

Comment: Ahhh i see, sorry the suggestion didn't help this time around!